# I meet a error when build gem5 x86, build/X86/ext/libelf/elf.c:34:29: error

Tags: build, scons, gem5

I meet a error when build gem5 x86, build/X86/ext/libelf/elf.c:34:29: error

```
Checking for compiler -Wno-free-nonheap-object support... (cached) yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
 [VER TAGS]  -> X86/sim/tags.cc
 [     CXX] X86/base/date.cc -> .o
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/libelf/elf.c -> .os
build/X86/ext/libelf/elf.c:34:29: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
  .libelf_arch  = LIBELF_ARCH,
                             ^
scons: *** [build/X86/ext/libelf/elf.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: It looks like an error in the *.c file. The error kinda makes it look like `LIBELF_ARCH` is a `#define` that evaluates to nothing.

Comment: Try running `scons -c` then `rm -rf .sconf_temp`, then your scons command line again.

Comment: It might be useful to provide more details e.g. what are you attempting to build what OS etc. To properly help perhaps consider creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Further, it's a rather small detail but an important one. It's best to ask a fully formed question rather than just posting your error.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue and fixed it by switching to a different version of gcc (from 11.2 to 7.5).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).